# Specifiying different packages for Pojos and DAOs with maven hibernate plugin

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, dao, pojo

I'd like to know if there is a way to have hbm2java and hbm2dao output files with different package names.
Currently i have them configured in my pom.xml as...

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-entities</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>hbm2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>generate-dao</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>hbm2dao</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <components>

                    <component>
                        <name>hbm2java</name>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                        <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
                    </component>

                    <component>
                        <name>hbm2dao</name>
                        <implementation>jdbcconfiguration</implementation>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                    </component>

                </components>

                <componentProperties>
                                  <packagename>it.extrasys.estav.cupiris.common.persistency</packagename>
                    <propertyfile>/src/main/resources/database.properties</propertyfile>
                    <configurationfile>/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
                    <templatepath>src/main/resources/template</templatepath>
                    <jdk5>true</jdk5>
                    <ejb3>true</ejb3>
                    <format>true</format>
                </componentProperties>

            </configuration>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                    <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1_3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

I also created templates for dao and pojo to generate classes with different packages but I all files are generated in the same directory.

Comment: I had the same problem I solved it here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662640/custom-hibernate-tool-exporter