# Custom hibernate tool exporter

Tags: hibernate, maven, hibernate-tools, hibernate3-maven-plugin

I use the maven plug in to generate pojo and dao :

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>hbm2java</goal>
            <goal>hbm2dao</goal> 
            <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <components>
        <component>
            <name>hbm2java</name>
            <implementation>configuration</implementation>
            <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        </component>
        <component>
            <name>hbm2dao</name>
            <implementation>configuration</implementation>
            <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        </component>
        <component>
            <name>hbm2ddl</name>
            <implementation>configuration</implementation>
            <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/sql</outputDirectory>
        </component>
    </components>
    <componentProperties>
        <jdk5>true</jdk5>
        <format>true</format>
        <configurationfile>src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>

        <drop>true</drop>
        <create>true</create>
        <outputfilename>init.sql</outputfilename>
        <templatepath>src/main/resources/templateftl</templatepath>

    </componentProperties>
</configuration>
```

awfully the dao and pojo are generated in the same package

In hibernate tools it is hardcoded

```
DAOExporter :  setFilePattern("{package-name}/{class-name}Home.java");
POJOExporter : setFilePattern("{package-name}/{class-name}.java");
```

I find it is extremly ugly and I would like to have pojo and dao in different package and also no suffixing the Dao by "Home" but just "Dao"

Do you know if there is some way to provide a custom Exporter implementation or configure something in the pluging to achieve this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I used JD-gui to decompile and read the code of the plugin and I managed to do it running 2 times the plugin with the goal hbmtemplate each times using a different template : one for the entity one for the dao.

I found out that it is possible to use a custom exporter by specifying it in exporterclass.
maven plugins lack some king of xsd...

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <id>genpojo</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>hbmtemplate</goal> 
                <goal>hbm2ddl</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <components>
                <component>
                    <name>hbmtemplate</name>
                    <implementation>configuration</implementation>
                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                </component>                        
                <component>
                    <name>hbm2ddl</name>
                    <implementation>configuration</implementation>
                    <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/sql</outputDirectory>
                </component>
            </components>
            <componentProperties>
                <jdk5>true</jdk5>
                <format>true</format>
                <configurationfile>src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
                <drop>true</drop>
                <create>true</create>
                <outputfilename>init.sql</outputfilename>
                <templatepath>src/main/resources/templateftl</templatepath>
                <filepattern>{package-name}/pojogen/{class-name}.java</filepattern>
                <template>pojo/Pojo.ftl</template>
            </componentProperties>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <id>gendao</id>
            <goals>                         
                <goal>hbmtemplate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <components>                        
                 <component>
                    <name>hbmtemplate</name>
                    <implementation>configuration</implementation>
                    <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                </component>
            </components>
            <componentProperties>
                <jdk5>true</jdk5>
                <format>true</format>
                <configurationfile>src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml</configurationfile>
                <drop>true</drop>
                <create>true</create>
                <templatepath>src/main/resources/templateftl</templatepath>
                <!--  <exporterclass>com.db.exporter.MyDAOExporter</exporterclass>-->
                <filepattern>{package-name}/daogen/{class-name}Dao.java</filepattern>
                <template>dao/daohome.ftl</template>
            </componentProperties>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>

</plugin>
```